# Calculate length of buffer for 16x8 LED matrix

Tags: arduino, adafruit

I'm working on a project with a [Adafruit 8x16 LED Matrix FeatherWing](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3149), which I want to use to display scrolling text. Looking at the example code provided via [the Arduino library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_LED_Backpack/blob/master/examples/minimatrix16x8/minimatrix16x8.ino#L115-L121), I've managed to come up with the following:

```
void updateDisplay()
{
    for (int8_t x = 16; x >= -36; x--)
    {
        matrix.clear();
        matrix.setCursor(x, 0);
        matrix.print("World");
        // matrix.print(displayText);
        matrix.writeDisplay();
        delay(100);
    }
}
```

Nothing too different from the sample code, except I've set `x` to `16` so the message starts from off the display on the left.

If I understand this correctly, the `-36` value is how many pixels is required to scroll the text off the other side of the display. That is to say, the buffer for "World" is `36` pixels wide. If this is the case, how can I work out the size of the buffer for an arbitrary string?

I'm guessing there's a method which I'm able to write (or exists) which can calculate it, or maybe the library already knows this info, in which case I need a way to access it.

You can see I have a `displayText` variable which I'm going to be updating with a duration, anything from "0 seconds" to "365 days" (and beyond), so I'm going to need to calculate this width each time the `displayText` value is updated - unless there's an easier way to solve this problem?

I welcome your advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very large thanks to Adam Bachman for helping me find the answer to this.

The following is his code, and demonstrates use of the `getTextBounds()` method for calculating the size of the buffer (and the weird way in which it's able to return multiple parameters to you):

```
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_LEDBackpack.h>

/************************ LED Matrix *******************************/
Adafruit_8x16minimatrix matrix = Adafruit_8x16minimatrix();

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
while(! Serial);
}

void loop() {
// void Adafruit_GFX::getTextBounds(const char *str, int16_t x, int16_t y,
//     int16_t *x1, int16_t *y1, uint16_t *w, uint16_t *h) {
int16_t x1, y1;
uint16_t w, h;

matrix.getTextBounds((const char*)"my string is here", 0, 0, &x1, &y1, &w, &h);

Serial.print("x1="); Serial.print(x1);
Serial.print(", y1="); Serial.print(y1);
Serial.print(", w="); Serial.print(w);
Serial.print(", h="); Serial.print(h);
Serial.println(" ");
delay(1000);
}
```

The output of which looks like this:

```
x1=0, y1=0, w=6, h=136
x1=0, y1=0, w=6, h=136
x1=0, y1=0, w=6, h=136
x1=0, y1=0, w=6, h=136
x1=0, y1=0, w=6, h=136
x1=0, y1=0, w=6, h=136
```

In this instance, because he's using the default rotation, it's the `h` value which we need, but in my instance, because I'd set `matrix.setRotation(1);`, I'd use the `w` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the length of a string using 
LengthA=StringA.length();

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringLength

I assume the font is fixed width, so multiply the font width by the string length and add a value to account for any spaces before or after the string if they are required.

If you don't have or don't send a clear command between strings, you would normally add enough spaces to clear the display at the start the next string.

I would imagine the spaces between characters are included in the font, if not you would need to add them.

Trevor